# tasklist command clarification

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

1)currently i am storing output into D:\Pro_Active_Monitor\Process_list.txt.I want to store the output into some delimited file.I mean Image Name,                     PID, Session Name,Session#,Mem Usage should be separated be some delimiter

```
tasklist  /FI "STATUS eq running" > D:\Pro_Active_Monitor\Process_list.txt.

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
csrss.exe                      660 Console                    1     91,996 K
ssonsvr.exe                   5284 Console                    1        464 K
taskhost.exe                   948 Console                    1     12,004 K
ccSvcHst.exe                  2412 Console                    1      4,716 K
dwm.exe                       5888 Console                    1     27,652 K
explorer.exe                  5192 Console                    1     70,048 K
igfxtray.exe                  1880 Console                    1      1,416 K
hkcmd.exe                     5540 Console                    1      1,460 K
igfxpers.exe                  2304 Console                    1      4,508 K
RtDCpl64.exe                  3300 Console                    1      1,936 K
concentr.exe                  2076 Console                    1      3,912 K
iexplore.exe                  2656 Console                    1     36,000 K
vpnui.exe                     1732 Console                    1      4,336 K
Receiver.exe                  4720 Console                    1     10,108 K
iexplore.exe                  5472 Console                    1   1,21,192 K
SCNotification.exe            4908 Console                    1     10,064 K
sametime.exe                  6216 Console                    1   1,49,500 K
nlnotes.exe                   6504 Console                    1     97,156 K
notes2.exe                    6704 Console                    1   1,51,980 K
wfcrun32.exe                  4668 Console                    1     11,960 K
ptSrv.exe                     6476 Console                    1        992 K
ntaskldr.exe                  4188 Console                    1     22,100 K
notepad++.exe                 6920 Console                    1     14,484 K
chrome.exe                   10384 Console                    1   1,69,240 K
chrome.exe                    8912 Console                    1     45,580 K
Greenshot.exe                 6372 Console                    1     48,264 K
EXCEL.EXE                     6236 Console                    1     82,048 K
wfica32.exe                  10956 Console                    1     35,872 K
wfica32.exe                   3876 Console                    1     37,284 K
iexplore.exe                  8008 Console                    1     27,216 K
jp2launcher.exe              10468 Console                    1     70,052 K
bzsm.exe                      7748 Console                    1     15,880 K
dllhost.exe                   8228 Console                    1      8,284 K
cmd.exe                       5636 Console                    1      4,916 K
conhost.exe                  10140 Console                    1      8,008 K
```

Comment: `tasklist /?` shows me a `/FO` parameter to choose the output format. `tasklist /FO csv` indeed shows me a list of comma separated columns.

Comment: @Stephan - why this is not an answer :) ?

Comment: @npocmaka wasn't sure if "Rtfm" is a valid answer...

Answer (score 3):

`tasklist` has a format option: `tasklist /fo csv` produces a comma separated list

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to use [`wmic`](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) as it already has CSV formatted output:

```
wmic process get ProcessID,Session,Caption,VirtualSize /Format:csv
```

[Here you can see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx) what properties of the processes you can get